# Nomad - How to spread a job across nodes that all have the same metadata without using a constraint

Tags: devops, nomad

I currently have this metadata in my clients
A row can have multiple columns and there is a machine on each row-col
So my meta data looks like this

```
 meta 
 {
   row = "1"
   col = "3"
   id = "12"
 }
```

What I would like to do is spread this job over the same row (nomad could choose any row but all the job instances in the count should then run on that row) but different columns, so I am trying to do this

```
#Spread across all columns equally
spread 
{
   attribute = "${meta.col}"
   weight    = 100
}

#Whatever row is chosen then use the same row for every instance
spread 
{
   attribute = "${meta.row}"
   weight    = 0 #This is incorrect and wont work
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this ?